# JavaScript obj.constructor vs obj.[[Prototype]]'s constructor

Tags: javascript

`Object.getPrototypeOf(z).constructor === z.constructor`

Is this true for every object `z` in JavaScript?

I mean is `z.constructor` just a shortcut allowing us to retrieve more easily
the constructor property of the object's internal `[[Prototype]]` property.

Or... are there cases in which the two differ and the `z.constructor` value
is different from the `Object.getPrototypeOf(z).constructor` value?

I think it is just shortcut but I am not sure as I don't find
this stated explicitly in any authoritative source of doc.

**EDIT**:
This code below shows that setting `Object.getPrototypeOf(z).constructor` implicitly sets the other value too. But setting `z.constructor` does not set the other value.
**So now I am puzzled... how is this implemented?** Seems `z.constructor` is not just a shortcut but some sort of copy. But if it's a copy why is it affected when we change/set the `Object.getPrototypeOf(z).constructor` to a new value?

```
    function Animal() {

        this.ttype = "Animal"

    }

    function Plant(){
        this.ttype = "Plant"
    }

    var p1 = new Plant();
    console.log(p1.constructor);
    console.log(p1.constructor === Object.getPrototypeOf(p1).constructor);
    p1.constructor = Animal;
    console.log(p1.constructor === Object.getPrototypeOf(p1).constructor);

    var p2 = new Plant();
    console.log(p2.constructor);
    console.log(p2.constructor === Object.getPrototypeOf(p2).constructor);
    Object.getPrototypeOf(p2).constructor = Animal;
    console.log(p2.constructor === Object.getPrototypeOf(p2).constructor);
    console.log(p2.constructor);
```

Comment: Your object could have a `constructor` property like: `z.constructor = () => 'custom'`. Also, if you have `z = Object.create(null)`, then `Object.getPrototypeOf(z).constructor` will throw an error

Comment: Hm... So it's not just a shortcut. But if I set `Object.getPrototypeOf(z).constructor` the two remain the same. How is this implemented?!

Comment: @adiga Let's leave aside the case when we created the object via `Object.create(null)` Let's say it has non-null `[[Prototype]]`

Comment: Unless the object has an *own* `constructor` property, the condition will be true

Comment: @adiga Oh... Wait... So... are you saying this is nothing more but the standard lookup process which happens for any property which we try to access on any object `z` (i.e. there's nothing special about the `z.constructor` property as such)?

Comment: It is standard prototype chain lookup. When you access `p1.constructor`, it will be looked directly under the `p1` object (own properties). If it is not found, then it will be looked inside it's `__proto__` or `[[Prototype]]` which is `Plant.prototype`. Here it is found and it will be returned.

Comment: If you access, say, `p1.hasOwnProperty`. it will check in `p1` -> then `Plant.prototype`. It's not found here either. So, it checks in `Object.getPrototypeOf(Plant.prototype)` which is `Object.prototype`. Here it is found and that will be used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `constructor` property of an object is normally inherited from it's prototype chain. There are two exceptions:

1. Objects whose prototype chain doesn't contain any objects. These be created using `Object.create(null)` and are useful for setting up look up tables that aren't affected by properties inherited from somewhere else.
2. Objects that have been assigned a local "own" property called `constructor`, as in

   ```
   myObject.constructor = 42;
   ```

   However, this is a technicality and not something you would expect to see in real code.

So leaving these aside, where is `constructor` inherited from?

By language design,  `constructor` is inherited from the constructor function's `prototype` property. Every plain vanilla function in JavaScript is set up with a `prototype` property with a non enumerable property called `constructor` set to the function object itself. By this means *any* standard function can be called as a constructor without modification. However the overhead is that standard functions never intended to be used as constructors have a `prototype` property anyway.

Now more complications:

3. The `prototype` property of a standard function object is writable. If it is updated to a new object value, objects constructed by the function will inherit `constructor` from the ammended `prototype` object - which would generally be different to the `constructor` value of the overwritten `prototype` value.
4. The `constructor` property of the `prototype` property of a function is not write protected.

   - In combination, these two factors allow setting up prototype chains of arbitrary length, *simulating in part the extension of classes in a class based language.* E.G. If `C` objects inherit from `B` which inherit from `A` you could write

     ```
     B.prototype = new A()  // B objects inherit from an instance of A,
                            // which inherits from A.prototype
     C.prototype = new B()  // C objects inherit from an instance of B,
                            // which inherits from B.prototype and A.prototype
     C.prototype.constructor = C;     // C objects inherit C as their constructor.
     ```

These classic rules for chaining prototypes are quite lax: you can change the `prototype` property multiple times without affecting the inheritance chain of previously created objects. However changing the `prototype` property of a constructor function multiple times has limited use (creating a polyfill for `Object.create` perhaps) and most unusual.

Note the `class` keyword syntax to create constructor functions renders this kind of manipulation obsolete - you can't change a class constructor functions `prototype` property, and if you extend a "class" the `prototype` property of the extended class inherits from the base class's `prototype` property while having its `constructor` property set to the extended constructor, both automatically.

Also note that arrow functions don't have a `prototype` property and cannot be used as constructors.

---

q1

> `Object.getPrototypeOf(z).constructor === z.constructor`
>   Is this true for every object z in JavaScript?

Yes, except for the exceptions listed under 1) and 2).

q2

> `p1.constructor = Animal;`

This creates an own property of `p1` that shadows the inherited `constructor`property which can no longer be accessed  (exception 2)

q3

> `Object.getPrototypeOf(p2).constructor = Animal;`

This line of code updates the `constructor` property of the object from where `p2` inherits its `constructor` value from, so `p2`'s inherited constructor property is now `Animal`. Other plant objects which similarly inherit from  `Plant.prototype` would also see `Animal` as their constructor.